# Does AppleID purchase history transfer between accounts when logging into same computer?

Tags: mac-appstore

I have 2 separate AppleIDs and noticed that purchases on one account populated the other when I logged into the other account with the app installed. Does purchase history transfer between the two accounts?

Comment: I think App Store lists all purchases for that machine. If you try to download one, or update it, it will request the other credentials at that time.

Comment: Correct, but you could add both accounts to the same family so that you can use others purchases